# Django-cms 2.3 - 'cms_tags' is not a valid tag library

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm trying to update my Django-cms from version 2.2 to 2.3 and when I try to "runserver", I get this error:

django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'cms_tags' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading cms.templatetags.cms_tags: cannot import name VersionAdapter

The installation of django-cms=2.3 worked perfectly,  but there is something somewhere broking everything.

Here's a list of what's installed on this virtualenv:

```
BeautifulSoup==3.2.0
Django==1.3.1
Fabric==1.4.3
MySQL-python==1.2.3
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.3
argparse==1.2.1
cmsplugin-filer==0.8.0
django-admin-tools==0.4.0
-e git://github.com/bmihelac/django-app-name-translation-in-    admin.git@c7b033bdfb54fee5217248f4e596aa23752185e0#egg=django_app_name_translation_in_admin-dev
django-appconf==0.4.1
django-classy-tags==0.3.4.1
django-cms==2.3
django-debug-toolbar==0.8.5
django-filer==0.8.5
-e git+https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack.git@d2b51143c8008be8523a78822002de1836b9f501#egg=django_haystack-dev
django-hvad==0.1.5
django-mptt==0.5.1
django-page-cms==1.4.5
django-permissions==1.0.3
django-reversion==1.4
django-sekizai==0.5
django-staticfiles==1.1.2
django-transmeta==0.6.2
easy-thumbnails==1.0-alpha-18
feedparser==5.0.1
html5lib==0.90
httplib2==0.7.2
ipython==0.11
poster==0.8.1
pycrypto==2.6
pysolr==2.1.0-beta
python-ptrace==0.6.4
simplejson==2.2.1
sorl-thumbnail==11.09
ssh==1.7.14
virtualenv==1.6.4
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VersionAdapter` belongs to `django-reversion` so you need need to upgrade (django-reversion) to version 1.6. See the `django-cms` installation notes:

```
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.3.3/getting_started/installation.html
```

Comment: I think you mean reversion==1.6